# error: Call to undeclared function '_mm_extract_epi16'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations

Tags: c, compiler-errors, intel, clion, sse

I am trying to use `_mm_extract_epi16` of the sse intel intrinsics in C Code, using CLion. Even though I put `#include <emmintrin.h>` in the header, I get an error message when using it:
[image]

The function in which this error occurs may compute the difference of two arrays:

```
size_t differenceArrs(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]){
    __m128i diff_xmm __attribute__((aligned(16)))= _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i acc_xmm __attribute__((aligned(16)))= _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i a_xmm;
    __m128i b_xmm;
    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < n-(n%16); i=i+16) {
        a_xmm = _mm_lddqu_si128((const __m128i *) a+i);
        b_xmm = _mm_lddqu_si128((const __m128i *) b+i);
        acc_xmm = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(a_xmm,b_xmm);
    }
    for( ;i<n;i++){
        a_xmm = _mm_lddqu_si128((const __m128i *) a+i);
        b_xmm = _mm_lddqu_si128((const __m128i *) b+i);
        acc_xmm = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(a_xmm,b_xmm);
    }

    acc_xmm = _mm_sad_epu8(diff_xmm,_mm_setzero_si128());
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(acc_xmm) + _mm_extract_epi16(acc_xmm, 4);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76449510/error-call-to-undeclared-function-mm-extract-epi16-iso-c99-and-later-do-not for some reason.  Compiles just fine (https://godbolt.org/z/5GMK6bbds) if you include `immintrin.h` and enable `-msse3` (for `_mm_lddqu_si128`, which isn't defined in `emmintrin.h`)  `_mm_extract_epi16` only requires SSE2, so it will definitely compile if `_mm_lddqu_si128` does.

Comment: Also, you know this is only checking the last compare, right?  You assign `acc_xmm = stuff` which doesn't accumulate anything, just overwrites it.  And the final result comes from a 16-byte load starting at the last 1 byte of each array, so loading 15 bytes past the end of the inputs. You scalar cleanup loop shouldn't be using 16-byte loads.  Presumably you'd notice this once you got it to compile and could debug it.